# Why doesn't laser ablation decompose sample

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I was reading up on LA-ICP-MS and MALDI. All the sources I read for LA-ICP-MS simply say that when the laser hits the sample immediately goes into the gas phase. Why doesn't the laser immediately break fragile molecules?

MALDI makes sense to me. You put the sample in a matrix that absorbs UV really well then hit the matrix-sample mix with a bunch of UV. The matrix explodes essentially, pushing the sample into the gas phase. The key here is that most of the energy of the laser doesn't go into the sample. It goes into the matrix. This is why the sample doesn't break down. LA-ICP-MS doesn't have the matrix to protect the sample so what gives?

Comment: Actually, the ICP will destroy any molecules that the laser ablation did not destroy. The LA just gets the sample to the awaiting ICP inferno.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. What about LAESI? This technique still has the laser ablation but it doesnt seem like it completely destroys the molecule.

Comment: I have not used LAESI, but I would assume the LA in that is deliberately relatively gentle. Hopefully, you will get a solid answer here!